# Python - difference iterating over columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, lambda

Just wanted a possible solution for iterating a difference over columns. Intuition says a simple for loop should be able to solve it, however, it's been a while and I am super rusty with my syntax etc. Or a group by with a lambda function?

Problem statement.

df looks like:

[image]

Obviously working with cohort files. I want to find the difference for col(n+1) - col(n) and iterate while grouping over the cohort group.

for example for 2014-04
my result should be
[image: df image]

Answer (score 0):

This simple call should do the trick:

```py
df.diff(-1, axis=1)
```

`diff`'s `axis=1` will calculate a difference on the column axis. Check the doc [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)